# How to Quantize(tensorflow lite) after restoring the ckpt

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

this is how I saved the model

```
checkpoint_path= "./train" 
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(encoder=encoder,
                                   decoder=decoder,
                                   optimizer = optimizer) 
ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, checkpoint_path, max_to_keep=5)
```

while training I saved after every epoch this

```
ckpt_manager.save()
```

Later restored the model

```
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(encoder=encoder,decoder=decoder,optimizer = optimizer)
ckpt.restore(checkpoint_path)
```

these are the files in checkpoint path
[image]

Now, here's my question; I want to quantize the model(post quantization), could you please tell how to do that?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization/quantize ?

Comment: my files are in .index form

Comment: Trained models can be quantized only during conversion to [TFLite](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/post_training). Are you interested in TFlite model?

Comment: Yes, But TfLite excepts only saved_model format, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

To convert checkpoints to a TFLite model, refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/r1/convert/python_api.md#convert-checkpoints- (source: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert)